# Word-wrap in a html table in mozilla

Tags: html

i have a HTML code its working fine in IE but its not working in Mozilla

please see code below

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>New Document</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<TABLE BGCOLOR="#B6EBFF" BORDER="3">
 <TR>
  <TD ALIGN="CENTER" STYLE="WORD-BREAK: BREAK-ALL;">
  thisisthetextabcdefghijklthisirrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrsthetextabcdefghijklthisisthetextabcdefghijklthisisthetextabcdefghijklthisisthetextabcdefghijklthisisthetextabcdefghijklthisisthetextabcdefghijklthisisthetextabcdefghijklthisisthetextabcdefghijklthisisthetextabcdefghijklthisisthetextabcdefghijkl

  </TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>
  <TD ALIGN="LEFT" BGCOLOR="FFFEA8">this is the text</TD>
 </TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Please Help

Comment: You have a single word. How, where should it break? What is the *normal* behavior you are expecting?

Comment: And your question is, what do you want to show?

Answer (score 0):

found this somewhere in my bookmarks it still just works with white-spaces. Or split the word on a certain character or server-sided.

```
td
{
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Comment: in my case there is no any white-spaces.
i have used this code but it doesnt work

Comment: that's what i said. Do you use any serverside scripting language like php?

Answer (score 0):

Word break and word wrap is for separate words, not for single very long word/sequence of characters. I hope this rings some bells for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you type  "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG"
this will produce

```
AARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
RRGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
G
```

I have taken my example from a couple different websites on google.  I have tested this on ff 5.0, IE 8.0, and Chrome 10.  It works on all of them.

```
.wrapword{
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
word-break: break-all;
white-space: normal;
}

<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:400px">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapword">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```